# Constraints with static cell are ambiguous

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I'm having some problems with properly setting up my static cell the way I want it while making it look good for different screen sizes.

Somehow I don't seem to get how constraints are supposed to work.

1. One of my views contains a `UIViewController` with a table view. However, if I change my preview device in the storyboard to, say, an iPad, the table view doesn't get resized. Am I supposed to handle stuff like this from code only or is there a way to handle this from the storyboard (like setting width and height to always fill)?
2. I'm trying to set up a static cell so it looks good on devices with different screen sizes. Things work well enough when I have only two elements (e.g. one label left and one label right - just like in the standard template), but as soon as I add more things, I'm running into a lot of warnings, e.g. that width and height are ambiguous.
   To me, it seems like I'm missing some key concept of constraints.

Look at the picture provided. What I want is the following:

[image]

- Date to be a certain distance away from my left table border
- The Stack View of volume + pic in centered in the middle
- pic & price & label (there is one more for the measurement) to be represent the right label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to actually try this at the moment but here's the path I would go.

Date:

1. Fixed Top, Bottom, & Leading to Container constraints to 8 (or whatever you'd like).

Volume Stack

1. Fixed Top & Bottom to Container constraints to 8.

Price Stack

1. Fixed Top, Bottom, & Trailing to Container constraints to 8.

You'll have some overlap issues with smaller screens at this point.  You should get the "Red Circle" to suggest which constraints to add.  Click and read each one and it will be specific enough to walk you through which you want resizing, resetting priority, etc.

*I hate dealing with constraints.

Good luck!  I'll try tonight to see if I gave an acceptable answer.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. This "sort of" worked, but not really (still lots of clipping/warnings). I then decided to go with UICollectionView instead, which worked pretty well out of the box.